# Не передается текст в действие котролера

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, fetch

У меня есть действие в API-контролере

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<bool> Create(string description)
{
  if (description != null) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

И есть JS-код

```
async function createPost() {
  let response = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:53060/api/post/`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify("Lorem ipsum")
  });

  console.log(await response.text());
}

createPost();
```

Я проверил через отладку - действие в контролере вызывается, но в него не передается параметр description и он равен null. Как передать через Fetch description в контролер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пре передаче в методах текста в `Body` необходимо им об этом указывать. Контроллер думает, что Вы передаете текст в `uri` (строке параметров) по умолчанию. 
Поэтому укажите вот так:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<bool> Create([FromBody]string description)
{
  if (description != null) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Оно же не знает, что текст, который Вы туда передаете, называется "description".

```
body: JSON.stringify({description:"Lorem ipsum"})
```

Comment: Не решило проблему(

Comment: Нет, тут не в параметрах дело, а в том, что он передает сообщение в body, а контроллер ищет данное значение в параметрах.